# Hidden user rights

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, security, permissions

I'm running `SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2`. I have a SQL Server user, that the application uses to connect to my database. I've removed the user from all roles except public and the login from all database roles.

When I log into my SQL Server, I'm able to connect to the database and although I can't read from any tables, I can still create and drop tables.

In querying

```
sys.database_role_members
sys.database_principals
sys.server_role_members
sys.server_principals
```

... I'm not able to find any roles associated with the SQL user.

Is there someplace else I can look to find out how this user has permission to create and drop tables?

What right needs to be revoked to remove this users ability to create and drop data objects?

Comment: Did you check `sys.database_permissions`? It seems you've only checked for role membership but not explicit grant permissions.

Answer (score 1):

I bet `CREATE TABLE` is one of the things that shows up here (replace `foo` with the login name you're concerned about):

```
SELECT p.[permission_name], p.class_desc
FROM sys.server_principals AS sp
INNER JOIN sys.database_principals AS dp
ON sp.sid = dp.sid
INNER JOIN sys.database_permissions AS p
ON dp.principal_id = p.grantee_principal_id
WHERE sp.name = N'foo'
AND p.state_desc = N'GRANT'
AND p.class_desc IN (N'DATABASE', N'SCHEMA');
```

For each database permission found that you don't want them to have, run a revoke (for example, for `CREATE TABLE`):

```
REVOKE CREATE TABLE TO foo;
```

And for each schema where they have explicit privileges (like `ALTER`) - just replace `schema` with the actual schema:

```
REVOKE ALTER ON SCHEMA::schema TO foo;
```

They may also own a schema (not `dbo`, but maybe their default schema or another schema), so check that:

```
SELECT s.name
FROM sys.server_principals AS sp
INNER JOIN sys.database_principals AS dp
ON sp.sid = dp.sid
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
ON dp.principal_id = s.principal_id
WHERE sp.name = N'foo';
```

If this comes up with any (again, replace `schema` with the actual schema):

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::schema TO dbo;
```

Comment: the first query only came back with Connect Database.  The second query came back with nothing.  I tried running the revoke anyway but that didn't help.  The user is still able to drop and create a table on the database.

Comment: Can they do this in any database or only this one? Is it a Windows login? If so, what groups is it a member of in AD?

Comment: It is not a windows login.  The user appears to be able to do this on all dtabases although I have been using a single database as my test case.

Comment: if it's helpful the login does not have any roles assigned to it either.

Answer (score 0):

I would check the following:

1. Check assumptions

   ```
   USE [ApplicationDB];

   SELECT 
       @@SERVERNAME AS [ServerName],
       @@SERVICENAME AS [Sql Instance],
       SUSER_SNAME() AS [Login - Connection],
       SUSER_NAME() AS [Login - Running as],
       USER_NAME() AS [User - Running as];

   EXECUTE AS LOGIN = N'foo';
   SELECT 
       @@SERVERNAME AS [ServerName],
       @@SERVICENAME AS [Sql Instance],
       SUSER_SNAME() AS [Login - Connection],
       SUSER_NAME() AS [Login - Running as],
       USER_NAME() AS [User - Running as];
   REVERT;
   GO
   ```
2. Double check db owner

   ```
   SELECT
     name
    ,SUSER_SNAME(D.owner_sid)
   FROM sys.databases AS D
   WHERE
     D.database_id = DB_ID()
   ```
3. Check effective permissions

   ```
   EXECUTE AS LOGIN = N'foo';
   SELECT 
       N'Database' AS [Scope Class],
       DB_NAME() AS [Scope Name],
       permission_name AS [Effective Permission in Scope],
       fbp.type,
       fbp.covering_permission_name
   FROM fn_builtin_permissions(N'DATABASE') AS fbp
   WHERE
       HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME(N'[PermissionsTest]', N'DATABASE',fbp.permission_name)<>0
   UNION ALL
   SELECT
       N'SCHEMA',
       s.name,
       permission_name AS [Effective Permission in Scope],
       fbp.type,
       fbp.covering_permission_name
   FROM sys.fn_builtin_permissions(N'SCHEMA') AS fbp
   CROSS JOIN sys.schemas AS S
   WHERE
       HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME(s.name, N'SCHEMA', fbp.permission_name) <> 0
       -- remove system schemas
       AND s.name NOT IN ('db_owner','db_accessadmin','db_securityadmin',
                           'db_ddladmin','db_backupoperator','db_datareader',
                           'db_datawriter','db_denydatareader', 'db_denydatawriter',
                           'INFORMATION_SCHEMA','sys', 'guest' /*,'dbo' */ ) 
   REVERT;
   ```
4. list assigned permissions

   ```
   SELECT
       DP.class_desc AS [Scope Class],
       CASE 
           WHEN class = 0 THEN 
               DB_NAME()
           WHEN class = 3 THEN
               SCHEMA_NAME(DP.major_id)
           WHEN minor_id = 0 THEN 
               OBJECT_NAME(major_id,DB_ID())
           ELSE 
               '<ignored>'
       END  AS [Scope Name],
       USER_NAME(COALESCE(DRM.role_principal_id,DP.grantee_principal_id)) AS grantee ,
       DP.permission_name AS [permission affected],
       DP.state_desc
   FROM sys.database_permissions AS DP
   LEFT JOIN sys.database_role_members AS DRM ON DP.grantee_principal_id = DRM.role_principal_id
   WHERE
       DP.grantee_principal_id <> 0 AND
       (
           DP.grantee_principal_id = USER_ID('foo') OR
           DRM.member_principal_id = USER_ID('foo') 
       )
   ```

   where `foo` is the user of interest

Comment: I've logged in as the sqlserver user that the apposes and yes username is returning the correct name.  Query number 2 came back as a blank set and query number 3 gives me the name of one of our developers as the owner.  Not the user that I'm troubleshooting.

Comment: Curious, did you run query 2 and 3 as the applications user? If so, please try the queries again as an admin. And You are *not* using "application roles" or impersonations?

Comment: Not using impersonation, No application roles defined.  I ran both queries as sysadmin account and got the same results.

Comment: Let me check my assumptions the application account can create both tables `create table dbo.myTable(id int )` and temp tables `create table #myTable(id int )`. Did you inspect public server role and public database role for any unwanted permissions?

Comment: the user can create tables and temp tables yes.  I'm not sure about the rights associated with the public role.  I'll need to look them up.

Comment: ok to test the public theory I created a new user assigned to the public role.  logged into that user and attempted to create a table.  The create table failed.

Comment: try schema ownership `SELECT name FROM sys.schemas AS S WHERE s.principal_id = USER_ID('foo')` where `foo` is the application account and run as sysadmin.

Comment: That query returns nothing as well.